# Doing a zero-copy move of data from a Linux kernel buffer to hard disk

Tags: linux-kernel

am trying to move data from a buffer in kernel space into the hard
disk without having to incur any additional copies from kernel buffer to
user buffers or any other kernel buffers. Any ideas/suggestions would be
most helpful.

The use case is basically a demux driver which collects data into a
demux buffer in kernel space and this buffer has to be emptied
periodically by copying the contents into a FUSE-based partition on the
disk. As the buffer gets full, a user process is signalled which then
determines the sector numbers on the disk the contents need to be copied
to.

I was hoping to mmap the above demux kernel buffer into user address
space and issue a write system call to the raw partition device. But
from what I can see, the this data is being cached by the kernel on its
way to the Hard Disk driver. And so I am assuming that involves
additional copies by the linux kernel.

At this point I am wondering if there is any other mechansim to do this
without involving additional copies by the kernel. I realize this is an
unsual usage scenario for non-embedded environments, but I would
appreciate any feedback on possible options.

BTW - I have tried using O_DIRECT when opening the raw partition, but
the subsequent write call fails if the buffer being passed is the
mmapped buffer.

Thanx!

Comment: Maybe you can do something with a pair of splice()'s.

Answer (score 3):

You need to expose your demux buffer as a file descriptor (presumably, if you're using `mmap()` then you're already doing this - great!).

On the kernel side, you then need to implement the `splice_read` member of `struct file_operations`.

On the userspace side, create a `pipe()`, then use `splice()` twice - once to move the data from the demux file descriptor into the pipe, and a second time to move the data from the pipe to the disk file.  Use the `SPLICE_F_MOVE` flag.

As documented in the `splice()` man page, it will avoid actual copies where it can, by copying references to pages of kernel memory rather than the pages themselves.

Comment: SPLICE_F_MOVE is no op in latest kernel code.. 2.6.31 onwards. So,  I am not sure if splice implementation actually tries for zero-copy transfer. Can you please confirm?

Comment: I tried to do some hands on testing but could not find any sample implementation of splice_read() and splice_write() in device drivers. Seems like no one has started using splice() yet. Do you have any references for splice_read()?

Comment: You may want to see the default splice implementation in fs/splice.c. http://lxr.linux.no/#linux+v3.2.7/fs/splice.c#L584